# exporting data from table in sql server to access?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Greetings

i wana know how can i export data from a table  to access through a sql job

i am using sql server 2008 and office 2007

Comment: Have you considered using the MSSQL2008 db as a data source within access?

Comment: no,but i know i can do that in through access ,,but i am asking about script so i can use it as sql job,,

Comment: So, I'm assuming to mean to have a job run and at the end of it have a table of data inserted into your Access db file.  I have not seen a way to directly export data from MSSQL to Access in that manner.  While I believe there is likely an method out there that includes some VB and SQL gymnastics, I recommend one of these two options: Export your data to an XLS, CSV or other flat file and have an import process pull that in to the Access DB or Write the query inside Access and have the MSSQL DB be the source.

Comment: thnx vinnie i will for ur post but to know is there a function in sql server enables me to export data to access,,i know i can do exporting to excel through wizard

Answer (score 0):

you can use SSIS "SQL Server Integration Service" For your problem.
also you can job SSIS Application in sql server.